# Can't download libprotobuf8 from trusty with aptitude

Tags: apt, package-management, aptitude

I'm running Ubuntu 17.04, "zesty".

I need to install version 8 of Google Protocol Buffer.

I can find the package at https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libprotobuf8/download

The instructions state that aptitude is the preferred way to download and install the package.

I've added the following line to the end of `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/p/protobuf trusty main
```

Then I run aptitude:

```
$ sudo aptitude install libprotobuf8=libprotobuf8_2.5.0-9ubuntu1_amd64.deb
Unable to find a version "libprotobuf8_2.5.0-9ubuntu1_amd64.deb" for the package "libprotobuf8"
Unable to apply some actions, aborting

$ sudo aptitude install libprotobuf8=2.5.0-9ubuntu1
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

Using apt-get doesn't work either:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libprotobuf8=2.5.0-9ubuntu1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Can't find a source to download version '2.5.0-9ubuntu1' of 'libprotobuf8:amd64'
```

When I run `sudo apt-get update`

I see

```
...
Err:3 http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/p/protobuf trusty/main amd64 Packages                                
  404  Not Found
...

W: The repository 'http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/p/protobuf trusty Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/p/protobuf/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Nevertheless, `/var/lib/dpkg/status` shows:

```
Package: libprotobuf8
Status: install ok config-files
Section: libs
Installed-Size: 1083
Architecture: amd64
Multi-Arch: same
Source: protobuf
Version: 2.5.0-9ubuntu1
Config-Version: 2.5.0-9ubuntu1
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14), libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1), libstdc++6 (>= 4.3), zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4)
 This package contains the runtime library needed for C++ applications.
Homepage: https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/
Original-Maintainer: Robert S. Edmonds <edmonds@debian.org>
```

However I can't find libprotobuf.so.8 anywhere on the system.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of ubuntu are you running?

Comment: Ubuntu 17.04, "zesty"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't get to install with suggested answers so downloaded the file from http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/p/protobuf

and

```
sudo apt install ./libprotobuf8_2.5.0-9ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: since you are running a newer version than this package is build for, this is your best option.

Answer (score 1):

1. libprotobuf8 is already in ubuntu repos, you could just simply install it with your package manager, apt-get or aptitude. Ex.

   `sudo apt-get install libprotobuf8`
2. That source you added is basically useless or not needed, I'd remove it
3. When specifing a package version just use the version, not the name & certainly not the .deb name. Ex.

   `sudo aptitude install libprotobuf8=2.5.0-9ubuntu1`

Comment: The apt-get call didn't work but the aptitude call did.

Comment: Spoke too soon. "sudo aptitude install libprotobuf8=2.5.0-9ubuntu1" results in "No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
"

Comment: *"libprotobuf8 is already in ubuntu repos"* Only in Trusty, which OP is obviously not running.